# JMeter populate user defined variables for forEach Controller

Tags: for-loop, groovy, jmeter

I have a service API to be tested which returns some default values of various parameters for different countries. country code being a template parameter of the service. i.e.

`http://${hostname}:${port}/country/${countryCode}`

One of the country code I can use is "ALL" (the others being "IN", "US" , "UK" , "MX" ...) which will return all the countries supported by the API and the response will contain the country code as well.
Thus I am able to populate all the country codes I need to test. The groovy scipt

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())

assert prev.isResponseCodeOK()

def countries = result.country
assert countries instanceof List // Should get as [IN, US, UK, MX] for e.g.
def numOfCountries = countries.size()
```

I am trying to use the variable "countries" which is a list of all the countries I need to test the service in a ForEachController. For this I will be needing the UDV Names in the format

```
country_1 , country_2 , country_3 ...
```

How do I save  the elements of list to the UDVs with that name format. The problem is I do not know or rather cannot assume how many countries are supported, so the UDVs cannot be named in advance.

Can that be done ? Am I going the correct way for the problem ? Any different approach is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with groovy, but here goes:

You have the list of countries- you get that in your script. If you create a for loop (in your groovy script), you can dynamically create your variable name (`"country_" + [loop iterator]`) and plug that into your `vars.put()`.

So:

```
for(int x=0; x < v.size(); x++)
{
    String country_name = "country_" + x;
    vars.put(country_name, v[x]);
}
```